# Dimension of Simplical circle

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am reading Crossley-Essential Topology. Definition "We say that a simplicial complex is n-dimensional if it has at least one n-simplex, but no (n + 1)-simplices, (n + 2)-simplices, etc".

The simplicial circle above is a one-dimensional simplicial complex with three 0-simplices (the vertices of the triangle) and three 1-simplices (the edges of the triangle)

Doubt: Since, simplical circle also has a triangle. Why don't we say that simplical circle has dimension 2 ?

Comment: Since there are no $n$-simplices for $n \geq 2$.

Comment: There is one 2-simplex, the original triangle which you have called the Simplical circle.

Comment: The triangle is not part of the simplicial complex. Otherwise it would be a disk, not a circle.

Comment: I understand that whenever I follow this definition of the dimension of simplical complex for $k-$simplex, it becomes a bit confusing. So, does this definition(the one I gave) befit the concept? or Should it be changed a bit?

Comment: @MUH basically, the dimension of the complex is the highest dimension of any  simplex inside it. The highest-dimensional simplex in any triangulation of a circle is an edge, of dimension 1.